# Tangent Bundle of Open Subset

Tags: differential-geometry

I have this question. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset. Prove that the $TU \cong U \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

I have been able to prove the following: $$TU=\bigsqcup_{x\in U} T_xU=\bigcup_{x\in U} \{x\} \times T_xU$$
And since $U$ is open, $T_xU=\mathbb{R}^n \implies TU=\bigcup_{x\in U} \{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$

How do I go around proving the isomorphism? Kind of stuck

Answer (score 1):

Let $ (U,\rho)$ be a chart of $X$ with co-ordiante functions $(x^1, \dots x^n)$. Let $\pi:U  \times \mathbb R^n$ be the usual bundle map  onto $X$.
 Then, we can define a "local trivialization"

$$f:\pi^{-1}(U)  \to U \times \mathbb R^n$$

given by
$$\left(p,\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\mid_p\right) \mapsto (p,(a_1, \dots a_n)).$$

Details regarding this map can be found [here, in the section "vector bundle structure on TM"](https://math.uchicago.edu/~chonoles/expository-notes/promys/promys2011-vectorbundles.pdf), but it is a diffeomorphism.